# Deck of Cards on a linked list and Riffle Shuffle

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, shuffle

Language: C

I made this function that turns a string that contains a deck of cards into a linked list of cards. Then I wanted to make a riffle shuffle, (for those who don't know, a riffle shuffle consists in cutting a deck in half, and then placing a card from each half, from the bottom to the top, in the new pile. So if I had these 4 cards: AS 2S 3S 4S and I shuffled it that way, I would get AS 3S 2S 4S). For my program I only use decks of 52 cards.

Anyway, here is my attempt at it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node {
  char value;
  char suit;
  struct node *next;
  struct node *prev;
} card;

card *create_card(char value, char suit)
{
    struct node *new_node = malloc(sizeof (*new_node));
    new_node->value       = value;
    new_node->suit        = suit;
    new_node->prev        = NULL;
    new_node->next        = NULL;
    return new_node;
}

void print_deck(card *head)
{
    int i=0;
    for ( ; head!=NULL ; head = head->next)
    {
        printf("%c%c ", head->value, head->suit);
        if((++i)%13==0)
            printf("\n");
    }
}

void free_deck(card *head) {
  card *temp = head;
  while (head != NULL) {
    temp = temp->next;
    free(head);
    head = temp;
  }
}

card* Remove_card_end(card** head)
{
    card* remove = *head;
    while(remove->next!=NULL) remove=remove->next;
    if (remove->prev == NULL) {
       *head = NULL;
       return remove;
     }
    remove->prev->next=NULL;
    remove->prev=NULL;

    return remove;
}

void Add_card(card* new_card, card** head, int index)
{
    if (*head == NULL) {
       *head = new_card;
       return;
     }

    card* add;
    card* add2;

    add=*head;
    add2=add->next;

    if(index<0) return;

    for(int i=0;i<index;i++)
    {
        add = add2;
        add2 = add2->next;
    }
        new_card->next=add2;
        add->next=new_card;

}
int main()
{
char deck[]="QC8S6C9S3DKCAS3CTS2S2C7C8D5D9D5H8C4STD9C3S2DJDAH5STH7D7SJH4CQHQDJS6DKDAC4HQS4D2H3H6H8H7H9H5CTCKSAD6SJCKH";

    int i;

    card *head = create_card(deck[0], deck[1]);
    card *temp;

    for(i = 2, temp = head; i < strlen(deck); i += 2, temp = temp->next)
    {
        temp->next = create_card(deck[i], deck[i+1]);
        temp->next->prev = temp;
    }

    printf("Original Deck:\n");

    print_deck(head);

    for(int m=25; m>=0; m--)
        Add_card(Remove_card_end(&head), &head, m);

    printf("\nShuffled Deck:\n");

    print_deck(head);

    free_deck(head);

    return 0;
}
```

I use the Remove_card_end function to remove the last card, and Add_card to add where I want, and with the loop in the main, it would follow the right sequence to complete the shuffle. It is buggy and doesn't complete the shuffle as I wanted it to. 
The output is:

Original Deck:
QC 8S 6C 9S 3D KC AS 3C TS 2S 2C 7C 8D 
5D 9D 5H 8C 4S TD 9C 3S 2D JD AH 5S TH 
7D 7S JH 4C QH QD JS 6D KD AC 4H QS 4D 
2H 3H 6H 8H 7H 9H 5C TC KS AD 6S JC KH

Shuffled Deck:
QC 7D 8S 7S 6C JH 9S 4C 3D QH KC QD AS 
JS 3C 6D TS KD 2S AC 2C 4H 7C QS 8D 4D 
5D 2H 9D 3H 5H 6H 8C 8H 4S 7H TD 9H 9C 
5C 3S TC 2D KS JD AD AH 6S 5S JC TH

What's wrong with my program? I believe there's something wrong with either the Add_card or the Remove_card_end functions, or maybe both.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With that kind of data structure - just a list you could make it really easy: split your original deck in half - take the pointer to the half way point and ensure half_way->prev->next = 0. (you now have 2 lists: deck1 and deck2). Create a 3rd list (shuffled_deck). Take the first card off deck1 and add to the top of shuffled_deck. take the first card off deck 2 and add to the top of shuffled_deck. Repeat until deck1 and deck2 are empty.